# Data read and output with a loop

Tags: php

I make an event list with a maximum of 4 events, saved in its own jason files.

I wrote this code for the output.

**JSON:**

> {"field1":"new york","field2":"1553404200","field3":1554415200}

**CODE:**

```
$jsonA = file_get_contents('code/data1.json');
$fieldsA = json_decode($jsonA, true);
$cityA = $fieldsA["field1"]; 
$dateStartA = $fieldsA["field2"];
$dateEndA = $fieldsA["field3"];

$jsonB = file_get_contents('code/data2.json');
$fieldsB = json_decode($jsonB, true);
$cityB = $fieldsB["field1"]; 
$dateStartB = $fieldsB["field2"];
$dateEndB = $fieldsB["field3"];

<div><?php echo $cityA . $dateStartA . " - " . $dateEndA?></div>
<div><?php echo $cityB . $dateStartB . " - " . $dateEndB?></div>
```

**The problem is:**

I have 4 events with each start and end date. So I have to do the same 8 times, but I do not want and should copy this code 8 times with a higher variable name...
In my project I have 13 fields and also 2 arrays to output the day and month name in my language. That's why it's so important not to copy everything 8 times.
I need a loop, but I do not know exactly how. I'm an absolute beginner, so please as simple as possible.

Comment: There is a function that will output the date as a string with localization: [`strftime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php). You don't need to loop through those arrays or make your own function.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it very easier and shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Great job with your attempt!

- You might just want to write a foreach and read your files and store it in an array.
- In your local server, you might just want to find the absolute path to your `code` folder. If you open your terminal, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> code directory and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in your terminal, you might see what your absolute path may look like. Then, paste upto before code directory in `$server_path`. Then, run the code, hopefully it would work.

---

```
function searchFilenames($array, $re)
{
    return preg_grep('/' . preg_quote($re, '/') . '/i', $array);
}

$server_path = '/path/to/your/localserver/';
$dir = $server_path . 'code';
$filename_array = searchFilenames(glob($dir . "/*"), 'data');

$fields = array();
foreach ($filename_array as $key => $filename) {
    $jsonA = file_get_contents($filename);
    $values = json_decode($jsonA, true);
    $fields[$key]["city"] = $values["field1"];
    $fields[$key]["dateStart"] = $values["field2"];
    $fields[$key]["dateEnd"] = $values["field3"];
}
var_dump($fields);
```

#### Output

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["city"]=>
    string(8) "new york"
    ["dateStart"]=>
    string(10) "1553404200"
    ["dateEnd"]=>
    int(1554415200)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["city"]=>
    string(6) "boston"
    ["dateStart"]=>
    string(10) "1553404200"
    ["dateEnd"]=>
    int(1554415200)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["city"]=>
    string(7) "chicago"
    ["dateStart"]=>
    string(10) "1553404200"
    ["dateEnd"]=>
    int(1554415200)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["city"]=>
    string(13) "washington dc"
    ["dateStart"]=>
    string(10) "1553404200"
    ["dateEnd"]=>
    int(1554415200)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["city"]=>
    string(5) "miami"
    ["dateStart"]=>
    string(10) "1553404200"
    ["dateEnd"]=>
    int(1554415200)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    ["city"]=>
    string(10) "los angles"
    ["dateStart"]=>
    string(10) "1553404200"
    ["dateEnd"]=>
    int(1554415200)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(3) {
    ["city"]=>
    string(7) "seattle"
    ["dateStart"]=>
    string(10) "1553404200"
    ["dateEnd"]=>
    int(1554415200)
  }
  [7]=>
  array(3) {
    ["city"]=>
    string(6) "austin"
    ["dateStart"]=>
    string(10) "1553404200"
    ["dateEnd"]=>
    int(1554415200)
  }
}
```